# How do you make these div elements display correctly?

Tags: html, css

I want to get div1 and div2 align horizontally but if I use display: inline-block there is a margin between these divs.

This is my html

```
<div>     
      <div id="content1">
        <div id="div1">contenido1</div>
        <div id="div2">contenido2</div>        
      </div>
      <div id="content2">contenido3</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#content1
{
    background-color:green;
    width: 800px;   
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#content2
{
    background-color:purple;
    width: 800px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#div1
{
    background-color:brown;
    width: 600px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#div2
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
    display: inline-block;
}
#div3
{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 600px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

How can this be done in CSS? I dont know what to do.

Comment: Display: inline-block produces some white space. Here's a link which might help you: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whitespace in inline content always (logically) collapses to a single space in the current font, like it does with regular text.

Easy solutions in no particular order:

1. Apply `font-size:0` to the parent container and reset it on the children.
2. Eliminate the whitespace from the source, ie. `<div id="div1">contenido1</div><div id="div2">contenido2</div>`
3. Use `float:left` instead, and accept the resulting mess with clearing elements.

If you have HTML-level control solution 2 is most practical, if it's a complex 3rd party template solution 1 is easiest since it only requires CSS overrides, and if you're developing something yourself solution 3 might be easiest depending on the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not float the two `div`'s with `overflow:hidden` on the container to control the float:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LK5LN/)

```
#content1
{
    background-color:green;
    width: 800px;   
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
#content2
{
    background-color:purple;
    width: 800px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#div1
{
    background-color:brown;
    width: 600px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
}
#div2
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how `inline-block` elements behave. [This link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) from the comments above explains some solutions nicely.

As an alternative, however, this is a nice place to use `display: table`. This way, whitespace in the markup does not affect how elements are displayed.

In this example:

1. `#content1` as the parent of the columns is given `display: table;`
2. `#div1` and `#div2` are given `display: table-cell;` to align them next to each other.

[jsBin Example!](http://jsbin.com/fehimu/2/edit)

[More information from the w3.org wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display#Values).

CSS

```
#content1
{
    background-color:green;
    width: 800px;   
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: table;
}
#content2
{
    background-color:purple;
    width: 800px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#div1
{
    background-color:brown;
    width: 600px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#div2
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#div3
{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 600px;
    border: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```